# Where are Angular property values stored after compile?

Tags: angular, webpack

I want to know if I can find the property values and change them on a compiled bundle.

Is it possible? If so where can I find them?

Example bundle files: [vendor/bundle if I'm not wrong](https://app.universign.com/sig/vendor.4027379aebcfec4ac408.bundle.js) && [main.js](https://app.universign.com/sig/main.4027379aebcfec4ac408.bundle.js)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by property values? Please elaborate.

Comment: There's this baseUrl variable. I want to change it like this: baseUrl = "https://someproxy.com/" + baseUrl;
So that whenever that variable is used it'll be proxied.

Comment: The correct way would be to modify the source and re-compile it. If it is not possible, a simple workaround is to open the JS files, and carefully replace 'baseUrl' variable with what you want.

Comment: The issue is I cannot find the variable. I've found that they are setting up this.baseUrl = baseUrl; on vendor/bundle file (webpack bootstrap file). Can you take a look, maybe I'm missing something...

Comment: The real quesiton is: Why do you need that?

Comment: Hahahah, check this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60187615/universign-disabling-pdf-download

Comment: As @MichaelD said, the correct way would be to modify the source, re-compile it and test the changes. It shouldn't be hard enough as it a simple URL change. Though you can find the variable you are searching for **main.js** file, you should not change it as it may produce un-expected outcomes on the HTTP methods dependent on it.

Comment: You can find the variable, but you cannot find the variable declaration.

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for baseUrl.

baseUrl is set via the html tag .